# Switch executa default direto

Tags: javascript, switch

Fiz uma calculadora de imc, mas o case cai direto no default ou não faz nada.
Como corrigir?
Qual maneira de simplificar cases?

```
let btnSubmit = document.querySelector('#btn-submit');
const formMedidas = document.querySelector('#form-control');
const inputMedidas = document.querySelector('.input-medidas');
const weightInput = document.querySelector('#peso');
const heightInput = document.querySelector('#altura');
const divContainer = document.querySelector('.container');

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const weight = +weightInput.value.replace(',', '.');
    const height = +heightInput.value.replace(',', '.');
    calculator(weight, height);
});

function calculator(weight, height) {
    const imc = (weight / (height * height)).toFixed(1);
    alert(imc) //resultado 24.1
    showResult(imc);
    return imc
}

const showResult = (imc) => {
    const divResult = document.createElement('div');
    divResult.classList.add('div-result');
    const yourResult = document.createElement('p');
    yourResult.classList.add('imcUser');
    divResult.appendChild(yourResult);
    divContainer.append(divResult);

    switch (imc) {
        case imc < 20:
            yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está abaixo do peso!`
            break

        case imc > 20 && imc <= 25:
            console.log(imc)
            yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está no Peso Ideal!`
            break

        case imc > 25 && imc <= 30:
            console.log(imc)
            yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está acima do seu peso ideal.`
            break

        case imc > 30 && imc <= 35:
            console.log(imc)
            yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.`
            break

        case imc > 35 && imc <= 40:
            yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.`
            break

        default:
            // yourResult.innerText = `Seu IMC é ${imc}.`
            break
    }
};
```

Comment: Conforme explicado no link indicado acima no box azul, `switch` não é a melhor opção pra esse caso. Já o `if` sugerido abaixo tem erros: se for igual a 20, por exemplo, não deveria ser peso ideal? E as mensagems acima de 35 e 40 são iguais mesmo? E também está redundante, não precisa testar os mesmos valores várias vezes, dá pra otimizar, algo assim: https://ideone.com/DUBKyK

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gastei um tempo com esse código, não fazia sentido não entrar nas condições do switch case. Fui dar uma pesquisada e cai numa resposta em outro forúm, que segundo um instrutor o switch case é utilizado para testar apenas igualdades, e não comparações de valores como no caso do cálculo do IMC, então o mais correto seria utilizar a estrutura condicial de IF e ELSES.

Sugiro uma alteração na sua formulá de calcular, para esta:

```
function calculator(weight, height) {
   const imc = (weight / Math.pow((height / 100), 2)).toFixed(1)
   showResult(imc);
}
```

Veja que utilizei o método pow para realizar a potência da altura. No código acima dividi a altura por 100 caso você queira recebê-la como centimentros, mas se for receber já como metros pode retirar essa parte da formula.

Já a função showResult com a estrutura de IF e ELSES, ficaria assim:

```
function showResult(imc) {
  if(imc < 20) {
    console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está abaixo do peso!`)
    return;
  }

  if(imc > 20 && imc <= 25) {
    console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está no peso ideal!`)
    return;
  }

  if(imc > 25 && imc <= 30) {
    console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está acima do seu peso ideal.`)
    return;
  }

  if(imc > 30 && imc <= 35) {
    console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.`)
  return;
  }

  if(imc > 35 && imc <= 40) {
    console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.\n Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.`)
    return;
  }

  console.log(`Seu IMC é ${imc}.`)
```

Note que como utilizei um 'return' em cada condição eu não precisei utilizar o else, pois se não entrar em nenhum dos ifs ele já vai pro final da função que retorna a mensagem 'default'.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Agora entendi realmente o uso adequado de switch, imaginei que if não ficaria organizado ou "elegante" e seria melhor um switch. Então, realmente devo voltar ao estado original utilizando if statement.

Comment: Hehehe, de nada. Que bom que ajudou, eu também pensei que o swith seria legal para esse caso, foi um aprendizado para mim também.

Answer (score -3):

A sua **altura** tem que ser divido por 100 para ficar em centimetro por isso não estava entrado em nenhuma case.

segue abaixo um exemplo, testei e rodou perfeitamente...

"Ex: calculator(92,160) "

function calculator(peso, altura) {

```
        var yourResult = document.getElementById('resi')
        //Dividido pra 100 para ficar em centimetros
        altura = altura / 100;
        //Fazendo calculo
        var imc = (peso / (altura * altura)).toFixed(1);



        switch (imc) {
            case imc < 20:
                console.log(imc)
                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + '  Você está abaixo do peso!'

                break

            case imc > 20 && imc <= 25:
                console.log(imc)
                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + ' Você está no Peso Ideal!'

                break

            case imc > 25 && imc <= 30:
                console.log(imc)
                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + ' Você está acima do seu peso ideal.'

                break

            case imc > 30 && imc <= 35:
                console.log(imc)
                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + ' Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.'

                break

            case imc > 35 && imc <= 40:
                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + ' Você está muito acima do seu peso ideal.'

                break

            default:

                yourResult.innerText = 'Seu IMC é ' + imc + ''
                break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Então, o alert está retornando 24.1 para o meu, eu testei em outros sites uns dão 24.9, outros deram 24.1 de resultado do meu imc.

Comment: Se liga no exemplo que coloquei acima e me diz se rodou ai